# Sybase removing duplicate data

Tags: sql, database, duplicates, sybase

I have noticed that a table in my database contains duplicate rows. This has happened on various dates.

When i run this query

```
 select  ACC_REF, CIRC_TYP, CIRC_CD, count(*) from table

 group by ACC_REF, CIRC_TYP, CIRC_CD

 having count(1)>1
```

I can see the rows which are duplicated and how many times it excists (always seems to be 2).

The rows do have a unique id on them, and i think it would be best to remove the value with the newest id

I want to select the data thats duplicated but only with the highest id so i can move it to another table before deleteing it.

Anyone know how i can do this select?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  max(id) as maxid, ACC_REF, CIRC_TYP, CIRC_CD, count(*) 
from table
group by ACC_REF, CIRC_TYP, CIRC_CD
having count(*)>1
```

Edit:

I think this is valid in Sybase, it will find ALL duplicates except the one with the lowest id

```
;with a as
(
select  ID, ACC_REF, CIRC_TYP, CIRC_CD, 
row_number() over (partition by ACC_REF, CIRC_TYP, CIRC_CD order by id) rn, 
from table
)
select ID, ACC_REF, CIRC_TYP, CIRC_CD
from a
where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It will only output the unique values from your current table along with the criteria you specified for duplicate entries.

This will allow you to do one step  "insert into new_table" from one single select statement. 
Without having to delete and then insert.

```
select 
         id
        ,acc_ref
        ,circ_typ
        ,circ_cd
from(
      select
             id
            ,acc_ref
            ,circ_typ
            ,circ_cd
            ,row_number() over ( partition by 
                                             acc_ref
                                            ,circ_typ
                                            ,circ_cd
                                order by id desc
                                ) as flag_multiple_id
      from Table
    ) a
where a.flag_multiple_id = 1 -- or > 1 if you want to see the duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1, table t2 WHERE t1.id < t2.id AND t1.ACC_REF = t2.ACC_REF AND t1.CIRC_TYP = t2.CIRC_TYP AND t1.CIRC_CD = t2.CIRC_CD
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM YOURTABLE t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT max(id) ID,
    ACC_REF,
    CIRC_TYP,
    CIRC_CD
  FROM YOURTABLE 
  GROUP BY ACC_REF,
    CIRC_TYP,
    CIRC_CD
  HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
  ) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id;
```

Comment: Hi,The value of the id is different on both rows so i cannot join.

Comment: Of course you can. This join is only to have the MAX(id) for the duplicated values and then select all the information about that row.

Comment: Ahh i see what you mean thanks for the info. i just thought it was on the id.